# Magento2.3: How to fix Undefined variable issue?

Tags: php, magento2.3, blocks, phtml

We are facing issues from the custom module which we have done for EMI calculator. The issue is when we try to load the category page from the megamenu, its throwing the below error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: productprice in /var/www/html/app/code/Butterfly/Emi/Block/Index/Index.php on line 52
```

Below is the code:

```
<?php


namespace Butterfly\Emi\Block\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_registry;
    protected $_categoryFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

    public function getCategory($categoryId) 
{
    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
    $category->load($categoryId);
    return $category;
}

public function getMinDownpayment($categoryId) 
{

    $products = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('downpayment')
   ->addAttributeToSort('downpayment', 'asc')
   ->setPage(1, 1);
   // $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
   if($products){
    foreach($products as $productprice){
        $productprice=$productprice['downpayment'];
    }
   }else{
    $productprice=0;
   }
    return $productprice;
} 
public function getMaxDownpayment($categoryId) 
{

    $products = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('downpayment')
   ->addAttributeToSort('downpayment', 'desc')
   ->setPage(1, 1);
   // $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');

      if($products){
    foreach($products as $productprice){
        $productprice=$productprice['downpayment'];
    }
   }else{
    $productprice=0;
   }
    return $productprice;
} 
public function getMinInstallment($categoryId) 
{

    $products = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('monthlyinstallment')
   ->addAttributeToSort('monthlyinstallment', 'asc')
   //->getFirstItem()
   ->setPage(1, 1);
      if($products){
    foreach($products as $productprice){
        $productprice=$productprice['monthlyinstallment'];
    }
   }else{
    $productprice=0;
   }
    return $productprice;
} 
public function getMaxInstallment($categoryId) 
{

    $products = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('monthlyinstallment')
   ->addAttributeToSort('monthlyinstallment', 'desc')
   //->getFirstItem()
   ->setPage(1, 1);
      if($products){
    foreach($products as $productprice){
        $productprice=$productprice['monthlyinstallment'];
    }
   }else{
    $productprice=0;
   }
    return $productprice;
} 

public function getProductlist($categoryId,$downpayment,$monthlyinstallment) 
{

    $hireprice= $downpayment + ($monthlyinstallment*18);
    $products = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('hireprice',array('lt'=>$hireprice))
   ->addAttributeToSort('hireprice', 'asc');
   //->setPage(1, 1);
   // $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    return $products;
} 

}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: first test you are able to get the $products by echo($products) or print_r($products) ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can replace your code with this

```
<?php


namespace Butterfly\Emi\Block\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_registry;
    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_productPrice;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

    public function getCategory($categoryId) 
{
    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
    $category->load($categoryId);
    return $category;
}

public function getMinDownpayment($categoryId) 
{

    $products = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('downpayment')
   ->addAttributeToSort('downpayment', 'asc')
   ->setPage(1, 1);
   // $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
   if($products){
   $this->_productPrice = 0;
    foreach($products as $productprice){
        $this->_productPrice += isset($productprice['downpayment']) ? $productprice['downpayment'] : 0;
    }
   }else{
    $this->_productPrice = 0;
   }
    return $this->_productPrice;
} 
public function getMaxDownpayment($categoryId) 
{

    $products = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('downpayment')
   ->addAttributeToSort('downpayment', 'desc')
   ->setPage(1, 1);
   // $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');

      if($products){
      $this->_productPrice = 0;
    foreach($products as $productprice){
        $this->_productPrice += isset($productprice['downpayment']) ? $productprice['downpayment'] : 0;
    }
   }else{
    $this->_productPrice = 0;
   }
    return $this->_productPrice;
} 
public function getMinInstallment($categoryId) 
{

    $products = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('monthlyinstallment')
   ->addAttributeToSort('monthlyinstallment', 'asc')
   //->getFirstItem()
   ->setPage(1, 1);
      if($products){
      $this->_productPrice = 0;
    foreach($products as $productprice){
        $this->_productPrice += isset($productprice['monthlyinstallment']) ? $productprice['monthlyinstallment'] : 0;
    }
   }else{
    $this->_productPrice = 0;
   }
    return $this->_productPrice;
} 
public function getMaxInstallment($categoryId) 
{

    $products = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('monthlyinstallment')
   ->addAttributeToSort('monthlyinstallment', 'desc')
   //->getFirstItem()
   ->setPage(1, 1);
      if($products){
        $this->_productPrice = 0;
    foreach($products as $productprice){
        $this->_productPrice += isset($productprice['monthlyinstallment']) ? $productprice['monthlyinstallment'] : 0;
    }
   }else{
    $this->_productPrice = 0;
   }
    return $this->_productPrice;
} 

public function getProductlist($categoryId,$downpayment,$monthlyinstallment) 
{

    $hireprice= $downpayment + ($monthlyinstallment*18);
    $products = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('hireprice',array('lt'=>$hireprice))
   ->addAttributeToSort('hireprice', 'asc');
   //->setPage(1, 1);
   // $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    return $products;
} 

}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: @Siva, I've updated my code in foreach loop you need to use **$this->_productPrice +=** instead of **$this->_productPrice =** this. Hope this will works for you.

Comment: Thanks. Its working.

Comment: You're most welcome. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just Declare

```
private $productPrice;
```

And Use `$this->productPrice` Instead of `$productPrice`

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to all the $productPrice to $this->productPrice?

Comment: the one you are returning

Comment: Ok. Let me try and update you

Comment: if it worked for you accept my answer

Comment: I have updated the code as you suggested and see that it doesn't work when we declare the variable as a private variable and it works when we declare it as a protected. Also, we have to put $this->productPrice in all occurrences.

Comment: When I have used the code as suggested by @Kishan Savaliya, it works for me. Anyway, thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Wellcome Happy Coding...